# Rails, CKEditor; trying to render partial based on contents of the edited string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I've just included the ckeditor in my rails app; works great. I have a PageComponent model which has a text field that stores the contents that are then rendered into the show view, like this:

```
<%= raw @page_component.page_content %>
```

I just had the idea that maybe I could include an erb statement within the page_content attribute text, like this:

```
<%= render :partial=>'some_partial' %>
```

but it doesn't appear to work. The text is saved properly into the field, but nothing appears on the page. This was just a basic idea test, and I'm not sure it's even possible as rails may have already gone through the whole response rendering thing at this point. Is doing something like this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, the `<%= %>` tags are **ERB** tags, so one way of solving your problem is to simply use the [**ERB** class provided in Ruby](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB.html) (and already included in your views and helpers) to translate and execute the contents of any tags in the the `page_content` string and give you the resulting string back.  The `binding()` parameter passed to the result method contains the current (Rails) context, allowing the string to be interpreted just like a normal Rails view.

You could put the following method in your PageComponent helper:

```
def translate_erb(string)
  ERB.new(string, 0).result(binding()) # 0 is a 'safety level' (see docs)
end
```

Then in your view, call that method like so:

```
<%= raw translate_erb(@page_component.page_content) %>
```

Whilst this will work, I'd highly recommend against it.  By implementing this, you are allowing the user a *lot* more flexibility than they should ever have and, as a result, this is a complete security disaster.  Ideally you should create your own markup or use some other method to add this functionality in such a way that you don't give the user total freedom to do whatever they want.  However, as long as you understand this, it is a viable method.  Just please be **very** careful how you use it!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, James. This functionality isn't exposed to all users, just a select subset of admin's in control of content. I tried implementing your solution, but I'm getting "undefined method `render' for main:Object" errors upon running it. Here's my model string that I'm passing to my translate_erb method: "<h1>
 Welcome to here... test</h1>
<%= render :partial => 'shared/article_list' %>" After looking at the api for ERB, I tried dorking with safety levels, etc, but still fails

Comment: perhaps you can't call render within a string passed to ERB.new ?

Comment: It seems that the ERB interpretation occurs within a different context, and thus it has no knowledge of the Rails environment in which you are using it.

I had a look at the API, and found the result method can have a binding passed to it which sets the context of the ERB string - the parameter is simply `binding()` (a method of `Kernel`).  I tested it and it worked for me - hope that solves it for you!  I'll edit my answer with this finding.

Comment: Thank you James; it's working now. Onto getting ckeditor to not strip out the rails tags on/from input so they're editable after being entered.